NEXT14 how to display 404, 403, 500 page or custom error message in production build?
I'm using next14 and calling API for the data fetching. How to handle different API status in the app. I want to display 404, 403 and 500 pages based on the response. Also would like to display other 422 error messages. In production build I'm getting generic error message which I don't want to display.
My custom APIhandler is as follows:
try {
  const res = await fetch(APIURL, APIHeaders);

  
  const data = await res.json();

  // Check if the response is ok
  if (!res.ok) {
    if (res.status === 404) {
        return;
    } else if (res.status === 403) {
        throw new Error(
            data.message 
        );
    } else if (method === "POST") {
        if (isErrorResponse(data)) {
            return data;
        } else if (isErrorMessage(data)) {
            data.message = data.message ? data.message : errorMessage;
            return data;
        }
    } else {
        throw new Error(errorMessage);
    }
  }

  if (revalidateTags) {
        revalidateTag(`${revalidateTags}`);
  }
  return data;
} catch (error: any) {
    throw error;
}

My Error message
export default function Error({
    error,
}: {
    error: Error & { digest?: string };
}) {
    const pathname = usePathname();

    console.log("Digest Number :", error.digest);

    return <p className="text-center mb-10">{error.message}</p>;
}

Can anyone share how to correct the error message and API handler file?
